# PHP Require/Include SSL

Tags: php, apache, ssl, php-ini, php-include

I am working on migrating an apache webserver to include SSL. I have installed the certificates, and am able to utilize Https without issue.

The webpage also have a database component. this works without error in the standard Http version.

When I migrate to Https I encounter an error and the Php script dies at any "include" or "require" lines. There is no error message or log message, it just dies.

If I edit the file to fully include all the data from that external file, it works fine again. I assume this is some type of SSL security to ensure I am including only those files which are secured. However, I can not seem to figure out how to allow these files to be included. They are just functions that I use in multiple files so I would prefer not to copy them into each file.

If anyone has encountered something like this any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Require line as asked for:

```
if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)){
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
$data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,true);
require_once __DIR__ . '/database.php'; ...
```

The full code has no issues on standard apache configuration

Comment: Please add your code, its hard to understand the problem otherwise.

Comment: hard to believe that because of the ssl you have include error. Check in php ini if display_errors is true, and set error_reporting to E_ALL and run again. If there was any error, it should appear.

Comment: Hi yes, both of those are true, and full error reporting is on. However it still fails to include the require files.